# Can I access CloudKit's metadata fields through NSPersistentCloudKitContainer?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, cloudkit

I've got a simple Core Data Entity that is synchronized with CloudKit via NSPersistentCloudKitContainer. I can read my local fields, but how can I read fields like "Created" or "Modified" from CloudKit?

Do I have to add them to my Core Data model and populate them myself?

P.S. In his fantastic WWDC talk "[Using Core Data with CloudKit](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/202/)", at around 21:40, Nick Gillet talks about how Core Data fields in the CloudKit store are prefixed with "CD_" to separate them from the ones CloudKit implements by default. Then he says: "You wouldn't believe how many people add modify date to their CKRecord". Like it's something redundant.